# Some of my captions are missing from Word's cross-references list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

When using Microsoft Word's caption and cross-referencing tools, only some of the figures with captions show up in the cross-referencing list (see the picture below). I've checked and double-checked, deleted and reinserted the captions, but they still won't show up.

[image: Word cross reference list with half of captions missing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be related to Word's Track Changes feature. Figures or captions with changes pending are unavailable, or only some are available in the cross-reference list. After accepting all changes to figures and captions, the full list is available to cross-reference.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in a newer version of Word (Microsoft 365 Word, version 2012)
For me the problem was that the caption was not listed under the reference type "figure" but under the translation "figuur".