# How do I retrieve a lost caption / text box?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, caption

I moved a figure but the caption (in a text box) didn't move along.  Now I lost it.  It's probably hidden behind some text.

When I search for text in the caption, search *does* find it and directs me to a page where the caption is not visible.  So, it seems I know on what page it is.

[This page addresses how to find a hidden text box](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010074_Finding_an_Invisible_Text_Box.html).
I have enabled *Show drawings and text boxes on screen* as well as field codes, and I am in *Print Layout*.  I have tried to go to the Home tab -> Select -> Select Objects.
Nothing helps.

How can I retrieve my lost caption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a find, and select it in the Navivation window, the box should be highlighted.

Right click on the box, select bring to front -> bring to front.

Or, after selecting the text in the Navigation window, click on the Format tab in the ribbon. You may be able to give very large Height or Width values to make it spill off the side of the page? You also have the option to align it, to ensure it is still on the page!

Or, within the Format tab, select the Selection pane, where you can turn change the order of the 'layers'

Comment: It's not highlighted.  Let me try your second suggestion.

Comment: Sorry @gerrit I'm lost, I thought your OP suggests that the Control F finds it? Are you saying it does not appear in the navigation window?

Comment: It appears in the navigation window, but nothing corresponding is highlighted at the page itself.

Comment: That *may* not matter. Select it in the Navigation Window, can you then get to the Format tab in the ribbon @gerrit

Comment: Yay.  Making it huge and then stating *Position: in line with text* did the trick.

Comment: might be related with: http://superuser.com/questions/633890/some-of-my-captions-are-missing-from-words-cross-references-list

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me to remove a hidden text box. Search  for text in the box. If more than one instance of the text shows up in the search results, left-click to highlight the text box you want to get rid of. Next, close the search window ("x" in the upper-right corner). The focus is now on the text you searched for, in the text box. Press Escape, which moves the focus from the text in the box to the box itself. Press Delete, the box should be gone. Verify by searching for the text again. See how it works by creating a new text and then following the steps on the box you can see.